# ActiveSync to Sync iPhone with my Application

Tags: c#, activesync

Would it be possible, to use ActiveSync on iPhone to sync Mail, Contact and Appointments with my Application? My application is developed with C#. Now, I thought, If I could implement something, that the iPhones can connect with ActiveSync to my Application and sync the contacts, mails and Appointments like the iPhone does with Exchange. Perhaps there are some samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to my knowledge ActiveSync exposes a set of APIs called RAPI.

you can google for this but I really wouldn't bet iPhone can be "forced" to work with ActiveSync (I can be wrong).